# Vector implementation with circular array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I am confused. I was reading about the implementation of vectors using arrays.While we were on the simple dynamic array implementation everything was okay.

It was mentioned that you can implement the vector by using an array in a *circular* fashion and that that will make the addition and removal of elements (for first and last) run in constant time. Isn't that what a linked list is supposed to do? 
I want to know how it works, but I couldn't really find an implementation or a proper explanation. Any information on what is the general idea and how to implement it is welcomed.

Edit: My guess is that new data should be written on the 'oldest' data and that the array has fixed size and that you must have a variable that stores the last used position.

Comment: Your question would make more sense to me if you replace "vector" with "queue". Didn't you perhaps mean that?

Comment: Where was it mentioned? I wager the statement was about addition and removal at both ends (front and back), not about arbitrary positions.

Comment: @Dukeling No, I do mean vector (Sadly).

Comment: Could you define properly what kind of operations your data structure has to have?

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant But we're talking about a "circular *array*" which I assume means a circular buffer a.k.a. ring buffer. No linked list in sight.

Comment: @Inwvr iterate, replace at position, delete from position. Would be done best with a linked list (probably), but I am interested in this particular implementation.

Comment: If you want it to behave like a vector don't you need an add operation? With regard to the three operation you mentioned, the structure can be implemented as an array but the only difference is the when you iterate it and you reach the end you just continue from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)

Unfortunately you cannot implement vector using it as you will not be able to insert in the middle or delete from the middle etc.

Comment: Not 100% what I am looking for, but it gives a very good start for research! Thank you.

Comment: What stops you inserting or erasing at the middle of a circular buffer? Of course you'd have to shuffle everything along into / out of the gap, but that's what `vector` does anyway.

Comment: @Steve: Indeed nothing prevents me to do it and vector can be implemented using circular buffer. In C/C++ one can even write outside the array/table - but what for.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++03 `vector` guarantees contiguous storage, that is to say for each `0 <= n < vec.size()`:

```
&vec[n] == &vec[0] + n
```

This means that you *cannot* use a circular buffer to implement `vector`. At the point you "wrap around" from the end of the buffer to the start, you violate this restriction.

In case you think that `operator[]` could return some proxy with an overloaded `operator&` that satisfies this requirement -- no, it can't, it's required to return `T&`.

Aside from this requirement I don't think there's anything in the standard to prevent implementing `vector` using a circular buffer. In the case where the buffer is full you'd do the same thing `vector` actually does -- reallocate to a larger buffer. The only difference in behaviour would be what happens when you erase or insert at the start. With a circular buffer all the other elements would stay still assuming sufficient space, whereas normally they all move. But the standard doesn't explicitly *require* them to move, and since iterators and references to all elements are invalidated when you insert or erase at the start, a program cannot legitimately depend on them moving in any particular way.

It's true that `std::list` can insert and remove at both the start and the end in constant time. So can `std::deque`.